# My rails app works on a Heroku domain but not on a specific domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku, with postgresql, that works fine on a Heroku domain:

`my-app.herokuapp.com`

But not on a specific domain:

`my-app.com`

It works until I try to submit a form and an error pops up:

"*The change you wanted was rejected. Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.*"

I thought the problem could be about postgresql, and I tryed this:

`rails db:create`

But I receive another error:

"*Couldn't create 'myapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.*"

**Edit 1 with more details:** I'm using Cloudflare. My database.yml file is like this: `/config/database.yml.tmp`

Comment: Do you have write access on my-app.com? I'd double check folder permissions.

Comment: Hi @triplej. Yes, I have

Comment: If you're deployed it the environment should be `production`.

Comment: thanks for answer @tadman, I just solved it with the approach on my auto-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it doing this:

1. In `production.rb` setting `config.force_ssl = false`
2. In Cloudflare
   setting SSL/TLS encryption mode from `Flexible` to `Full`